# Passing data through Table View and Map View... how does it work?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uitableview, mkannotation

My app has a TabBar with two views. One is a map and other is a table view with search field. In table view controller I get some places (with coordinates) through JSON. I need to know how to retrieve these informations to put an Annotation in a map.

in TABLE VIEW:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
titleLocation       = [ streets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
location.latitude   = [ [ latitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] doubleValue];
location.longitude  = [ [ longitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] doubleValue];

[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
[mvc release];
```

I know it will not work, but I don't know how to pass this values for MapViewController or my MapViewAnnotation then put into MapViewController. This last one I think is better then the first one.

Could you help me?
Thanks a lot

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    titleLocation       = [ streets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
    location.latitude   = [ [ latitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] doubleValue];
    location.longitude  = [ [ longitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] doubleValue];

    MapViewAnnotation *mva = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:titleLocation andSubtitle:@"Clique para fazer sua contribuição" andCoordinate:location];

    NSLog(@"Lat/Log: %f/%f", location.latitude, location.longitude);

    [mvc setAnnotation:mva];
    [mvc.mapView addAnnotation:mva]; 

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    [mvc release];  
}
```

I put like this but it still doesn't work. The Annotation doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the map is always on tab index 0, you can access that `MapViewController` directly using the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array:

```
MapViewController *mvc = (MapViewController *)
                     [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
titleLocation       = [ streets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
location.latitude   = [ [ latitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] doubleValue];
location.longitude  = [ [ longitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] doubleValue];

//Here, call some method in MapViewController that takes a location and title
//and creates an annotation from it and adds it to the map view...
[mvc makeAnnotationAtLocation:location title:titleLocation];

[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

//(do not release mvc)
```

The `makeAnnotationAtLocation:title:` method might look like this:

```
- (void)makeAnnotationAtLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord title:(NSString *)locTitle
{
    YourAnnotationClass *yac = [[YourAnnotationClass alloc] init];
    yac.coordinate = coord;
    yac.title = locTitle;
    [mapView addAnnotation:yac];
    [yac release];

    //center map on coord if you want to...
}
```

Comment: I have this method on MapViewAnnotation class and not in MapViewController. The method is
    
     initWithTitle:andSubtitle:andCoordinate:

I'm still confusing MVC things.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you create a method in MapViewController that will create and add the annotation on behalf of the second tab.  It's better if one view controller doesn't directly access the controls on another view controller. Add the method makeAnnotationAtLocation to MapViewController.  In that method, you can create the annotation using the annotation class` initWithTitle method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working fine. I don't know why but when I call the makeAnnotationAtLocation method in my table view, Xcode says (a warning) that this instance method was not found in MapViewController. But it has worked fine. I was thinking if it could cause some problems in future. I guess not, but... I don't know.

Comment: You need to declare the method in the MapViewController.h file to make the warning go away (the actual code of the method stays in the .m file but you need to add the method header in the interface so other code can be sure such a method exists).